# ModX FormIt: validation error and success at the same time

Tags: forms, validation, modx, modx-revolution, formit

I create my form in ModX with FormIt:

```
[[!FormIt?
    &hooks=`email`
    &emailTpl=`registerEmailTpl`
    &emailSubject=`New Registration on Huayang English Website`
    &emailTo=`toto@gmail.com`
    &successMessage=`Your application has been successfully sent to Huayang.`
    &emailFrom=`contact@studychineseinyunnan.com`
    &emailFromName=`Huayang School`
    &submitVar=`registerForm`
    &validate=`given_name:required, 
        family_name:required, 
        birthday:required,
        gender:required,
        address:required,
        city:required,
        state:required,
        country:required,
        zip:required,
        email:required,
        phone:required,
        passport_number:required,
        place_of_issue:required,
        date_of_issue:required,
        expiration_date:required,
        campus:required,
        class_type:required` 
]]
```

The issue is that I always get a validation error, even if I input information for all required form inputs. The weird thing is that the form seems to validate: the success email is sent and the `[[!+fi.successMessage]]` is shown. But on the other hand, the `[[+fi.validation_error_message]]` is shown too and `[[!+fi.validation_error]]` equals to `1`. `[[+errors]]` is empty though as well as `[[!+fi.error]]` which is supposed to contain the validation errors..

So, it seems the form is validating and not validating at the same time.

How can I debug the form and find where the validation error comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are there multiple forms on the page that might be clashing? If so try setting another &prefix for one of the FormIt's.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the **notempty** output modifier for the validation error?

```
[[!+fi.validation_error_message:notempty=`<p>[[!+fi.validation_error_message]]</p>`]]
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it doesn't work. With that code, the error message is never displayed, even if it contains something. [[!+fi.validation_error_message:notempty=`<p>[[!+fi.validation_error_message]]</p>`]] won't output anything but <p>[[!+fi.validation_error_message]]</p> will. Same thing with successMessage. ModX bug?

Comment: Can you post the complete form so we can take a look.